# web app authentication

Tags: authentication, web-applications

I have a scenario where I have a web application hosted externally (ie: the webserver is not a member of my internal active directory domain).

I would like to authenticate users of the web app using their active directory credentials.

Is there a product or some setup I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: The most brain dead thing that I can think of is have my web app call to a service that sits on a domain machine and uses a System.DirectoryServices example...   to sent back an authentication token.   Is there a better way(ie off the shelf, or...)?

Answer (score 2):

Generally this is achieved by authenticating to the AD server with LDAP.  I'd recommend using LDAP+SSL to keep the passwords from going out in plaintext, and other than that you should be fine - as long as there aren't any firewalls in the way.